# Shortcut ctrl+' for "Show integrated terminal" not working in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

The keyboard shortcut for "Show integrated terminal" (ctrl+') is not working.

I tried uninstalling and deleting install folders, testing with Insiders build but nothing helped.

The shortcuts for Output, Debug console are working.

Latest version 1.17.0 x64

Comment: As far as I remember the shortcut is ctrl+\`(backtick) , not quote

Comment: Alex, you are so right.
Thank you.

Comment: Yeah, backticks (Shift+ The Key left of 1) are *very* easy to confuse with single quotes.

Answer (score 13):

Please try <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd>. I think it helps you.

Answer (score 5):

On Windows also double check that your keyboard is set to `English (United States)`.

Very confusingly, on `English (United Kingdom)`, the backtick did insert keys correctly in the code, but under the keyboard shortcuts, if I tried to set a key it instead gave something called `oem_8`.

Comment: My keyboard was on Japanese and reverting it to `English (United States)` solved my issue. Thanks!

Comment: same for me. have uk keyboard. tried to edit "keybindings.json" by typing "ctrl+`"  for switching terminal and editor focus but it had no effect. i then went to "keyboard shortcuts" ui version and assigned "ctrl+`" for "workbench.action.terminal.focus" and the same combo for "workbench.action.focusActiveEditorGroup" and both the "keyboard shortcuts" ui and the keybindings.json assigned "ctrl+oem_8". then toggling focus and hence location of cursor between editor panel and terminal now works.

Comment: i meant "ctrl+`" where it shows only "ctrl+". i copy/pasted shortcut from vscode and the formatting did not come out correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl+' (where the @ symbol is) will open the VS Code Integrated Terminal on Windows 10

Comment: Keyboard keys do not have the same alternative uses everywhere. You probably want to find a different way of identifiying the key you mean.